# Package cuda-license-7-5 is obsoleted by cuda-libs

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am installing cuda-repo-rhel7-7-5-local-7.5-18.x86_64.rpm

When I executed `yum install cuda` the error seems to be related to

> Package cuda-license-7-5 is obsoleted by cuda-libs, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements

I tried the suggestions but they didn't work.

> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

the output of

> $ uname -m && cat /etc/*release

```
x86_64
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

the full output install:

> $ sudo yum install cuda

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * epel: download-ib01.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cuda.x86_64 1:7.5.18-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cuda-libs(x86-64) = 1:7.5.18-3.el7.nux for package: 1:cuda-7.5.18-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnvvm.so.3()(64bit) for package: 1:cuda-7.5.18-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cuda-libs.x86_64 1:7.5.18-3.el7.nux will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcuda.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:cuda-libs-7.5.18-3.el7.nux.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cuda-driver-dev-7-5.x86_64 0:7.5-18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cuda-license-7-5 = 7.5-18 for package: cuda-driver-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
Package cuda-license-7-5 is obsoleted by cuda-libs, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: cuda-driver-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64 (cuda-7-5-local)
           Requires: cuda-license-7-5 = 7.5-18
           Installing: 1:cuda-libs-7.5.18-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               cuda-license-7-5 = 1:7.5.18-3.el7.nux
           Available: cuda-license-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64 (cuda-7-5-local)
               cuda-license-7-5 = 7.5-18
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: This is a package management question rather anything to do with CUDA programming, per se, and would be better asked somewhere else than on [SO]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

By default, CentOS 7 tries to download cuda7.5 (I guess it is seen by CentOs as the latest stable release)

```
sudo yum install cuda-devel
...
Package cuda-license-7-5 is obsoleted by cuda-libs, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
```

Instead, just install the **cuda-8-0** package!

```
sudo yum install cuda-8-0
```

It does not depend on the obsolete cuda-license-7-5 package.

**Note:** at the end of the installation, I had some issues with the key, this can be avoided with (not recommended)

```
sudo yum install cuda-8-0 --nogpgcheck
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed, for me. I don't actually know why a correct answer has to be downvoted only because the question is in wrong section/stack. Take a chill pill everyone.